# Grunt how to set up a task to invoke a plugin more than once

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I use requirejs to distribute the code into a single file.

In grunt.initConfig, I have:

```
grunt.initConfig({

   requirejs: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                paths: requirejs_path,
                shim:require_shim,

                baseUrl : "./mobile",
                name: "mobilemain",
                out: "./mobile/dist/main.js",
                removeCombined: true,
                findNestedDependencies: true,
                optimize: "uglify2",
                wrap: true,
                uglify2: requirejs_uglify2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this this part of code to set up requirejs. and I use

```
grunt.registerTask("distribute", ["typescript", "requirejs"]);
```

to register it to a task `distribute`, all works fine.

Now I want to call requirejs twice in the `distribute` task, once for mobile and once for desktop. Basically I will need to change the `baseUrl`, `name`, and `out` config in the above code.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grunt-contrib-requirejs is a multitask where you can simply configure as much sub-tasks as you want (using the options property)

```
grunt.initConfig({

   requirejs: {

        // define your base options which are the same for both tasks
        options: {
            paths: requirejs_path,
            shim:require_shim,
            removeCombined: true,
            findNestedDependencies: true,
            optimize: "uglify2",
            wrap: true,
            uglify2: requirejs_uglify2
        },

        // your first task which contains the 3 options which should be used 
        compile: {
            options: {
                baseUrl : "./mobile",
                name: "mobilemain",
                out: "./mobile/dist/main.js"
            }
        },

        // your second task which contains the 3 options which should be used 
        compile2: {
            options: {
                baseUrl : "...",
                name: "...",
                out: "..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then you can leave your alias-task `distribute` as it is, because grunt will run all sub-tasks if none is specified

```
grunt.registerTask("distribute", ["typescript", "requirejs"]);
```

or you can simply just run a single sub-task using the colon-notation:

```
grunt.registerTask("distribute", ["typescript", "requirejs:compile", "requirejs:compile2"]);
```

the second one would be useful if you absolutly must guarantee, that `compile` needs to be run before `compile2` (remember: [javascript does not guarantee property order in objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order))